# vim - indentation of C++ constructor initialization list problem

Tags: c++, vim, ide

I'm using vim 7.0.

I want the following code be indented in the following way (initialization list in the same indentation as constructor):

```
  A::A() :
  a1(10),
  a2(10),
  a3(10)
  {
  }
```

According to vim help this can be done by setting:

```
set cino+=i0
```

But this setting yields (only a1 is indented correctly):

```
A::A() :
a1(10),
    a2(10),
    a3(10)
{
}
```

Setting cino+=i1 indents correctly a1..a3 with 1 space indentation.

Comment: I see exactly the same problem with EMACS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html) and a little experiment, the following could help:

```
:set cino=i-s
```

Seems to be indenting init list exactly as you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Basically I had a quick play with the cino options.  Not sure if it will affect any of your other formatting preferences but looks ok to me.

```
:set cino=i0,n0,+0
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a genuine bug in vim since `cino=i1` does the right thing, but `cino=i0` doesn't. `:help bugs` for information on what to do from here.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried "set smartindent"? i think it does what you want.

Comment: Do you have a clue what I set it to?

Comment: you mean you want cindent, and set options to get the effect of the first code block? 

i just mean with all the default setting, (without the "set cino+=i0"), "set smartindent" does exactly, the same indent as the first code block.