# Vim: indentation of C++ nested initialization list problem

Tags: vim, indentation, neovim

I do not want special indentation for initialization lists and scope declarations, so I have in my .vimrc `set cinoptions=i-s,g0` (according to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973471)). It does the trick:

```
class Proletariat {
public:
  Proletariat();

private:
  bool freedom;
  int workShift;
}

Proletariat::Proletariat():
freedom(false),
workShift(12) {
  pogrom();
}
```

But it works fine just until code becomes included into some block, e.g.:

```
namespace ClassWar {
  class Proletariat {
  public:
    Proletariat();

  private:
    bool freedom;
    int workShift;
  }

  Proletariat::Proletariat():
    freedom(false),
    workShift(12) {
      pogrom();
    }
}
```

As you can see, scope declarations still not indented, but initialization list is.

I know that it is possible to play with continuation lines option `+N`, but it (obviously) breaks continuation lines indentation.

So what reason is for such behaviour and how it could be changed?

Vim and Neovim deal identically with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seems it is actually [incorrect behavior](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/4094).